# Qt Under LGPL: How to distribute changes to Qt source code?

Tags: qt

We've developed a commercial Qt application with Qt under LGPL. We link dynamically. We also made a few changes to a couple of files in Qt to better suit our needs. I realize that according to LGPL, I must make those changes publicly available.

My question is how is that done?

1. Do I set a webpage on my domain with the modified source codes available for download?
2. Do I distribute the modified source code in a folder on the client target machine after installation?
3. Another
   way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply have to make them available on request.

It can be a file on your web server, it could just be emailing them to anyone that asks, you can even supply them on floppy disk and make a charge for it.

Ideally you would also contribute the changes back to Qt  if it's a bug fix or feature that could be useful to other people, then it may be incorporated in future editions and youcould then just use the standard build.

ps. The letter of the GPL says that you have to provide everything that is needed to create your modified build - so the full Qt sources and the build files. However for a large complex project like Qt, if you have only modified a couple of files it would be useful to offer a download of just these (or even a diff against the specific Qt version)

Comment: Do I have to actively ADVERTIZE that I made changes to Qt? How would users know about this page on my web server offering to download a change to Qt?

Comment: In the license files distributed with your app you simply say that this app uses a modified Qt published under the LGPL and your contact details for anyone wanting the source.

Comment: You could also have a clone on gitorious.org and put your changes there. If they are of general interest, you might even want to have them merged to main Qt (which takes the maintenance burden from you)

Comment: Oh, so I have to include the text of LGPL and add comments there about my changes?

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html although you should also have a license file for your app making it clear that it's only the Qt part that is LGPL

Answer (score 2):

According to the licence you need to provide your changes back to the community, not just to your customer.

The easiest way is forking the main Qt repository on http://qt.gitorious.org/qt and commit your changes there.